# How to query for namespace dynamically using Linq to XML

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have 290 Group Policy Backup xml files which I need to enumerate in separate folders.

With each Group Policy backup xml file, I need to query the Policy settings.

Anyone who's looked at a Group Policy xml backup file before would know they're chock-a-block full of Namespace declarations.

I want to know, using Linq to XML, as I query each xml file, how can I dynamically query the XML the Namespace and then append the Namespace into the Linq query for the child nodes/values?

Here are some examples of the xml structure.

```
  <User>
    <ExtensionData>
      <Extension xmlns:q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Scripts" xsi:type="q1:Scripts">
        <q1:Script>


    <ExtensionData>
      <Extension xmlns:q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/IE" xsi:type="q1:InternetExplorerSettings">
        <q1:PreferenceMode>true</q1:PreferenceMode>


    <ExtensionData>
      <Extension xmlns:q2="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Registry" xsi:type="q2:RegistrySettings">
        <q2:Policy>
          <q2:Name>Disable changing accessibility settings</q2:Name>
          <q2:State>Enabled</q2:State>


    <ExtensionData>
      <Extension xmlns:q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/DriveMaps" xsi:type="q1:DriveMapSettings">
        <q1:DriveMapSettings clsid="{8FDDCC1A-0C3C-43cd-A6B4-71A6DF20DA8C}">
```

My initial code looks like this:

```
Dim NS As XNamespace = "http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings"
NodeValue = XDoc.Descendants(NS + NodeName).First().Value
```

As you can see I'm going to face literally dozens of different Namespaces, at this stage I don't even know what they all are.

My end-task is to trawl through 290 directories, each containing one Group Policy xml backup file. I then need to read the Policy Name from each of the settings contained within the backup file.

Because I don't know what Policy settings each xml flie will contain, I don't know what Namespace(s) I need to use when attempting to read the xml values. Each xml file may even contain multiple namespaces.

How do I dynamically read the Namespace in Linq so I can read the values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with:

```
Dim ListOfNamespaces = z.Root.DescendantsAndSelf.Attributes().Where(Function(a) a.IsNamespaceDeclaration).GroupBy(Function(a) If(a.Name.[Namespace] = XNamespace.None, [String].Empty, a.Name.LocalName), Function(a) XNamespace.[Get](a.Value)).ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(g) g.First())
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you care about these namespaces? i.e. Do you distinguish them and do different kind of processing depending on the namespace-uri? If you don't (e.g. you just display something) you can do something like this:

```
XDoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Extension")
```

This should select all Extension elements regardless of the namespace. Alternatively, if you need to query elements using namespaces instead of hardcoding one you could do something like this:

```
foreach(XElement extensionElement in XDoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Extension")
{
   var ns = extensionElement.Name.NamespaceName;
   Console.WriteLine(extensionElement(ns + "DriveMapSettings"));
}
```

Comment: Hey, unfortunately yes I care about the namespaces as the xml structure is significantly different between them.

Answer (score 0):

`From e In XDoc.Descendants Group By e.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName` should find all distinct namespaces, but it is untested.